# Select one speicific row with one checkmark using UITbaleView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode4, xcode5

**Plz anyone tell me how i select the row at one time with checkmark while other row are not checkmark.I tried but in my case there is mutiple row selected with checkmark. Basically I want to save one row with checkmark when i select another row then previous row deselect and this row select with checkmark. Here is my Code**

```
    - (NSString *)getKeyForIndex:(int)index
    {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"KEY%d",index];
    }
    - (BOOL) getCheckedForIndex:(int)index
    {
     if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:[self getKeyForIndex:index]]boolValue]==YES)
     {
     return YES;
     }
     else
    {
    return NO;

       } }


- (void) checkedCellAtIndex:(int)index
    {    BOOL boolChecked = [self getCheckedForIndex:index];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!boolChecked] forKey:[self getKeyForIndex:index]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {
      return List.count;
    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
      static NSString *subviewCells = @"Cells";

       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:subviewCells];
      if (cell == nil)
     {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:subviewCells];
      }
        cell.textLabel.text = [List objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
          return cell;
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

         [self checkedCellAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      if([self getCheckedForIndex:indexPath.row]==YES)
       {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
     }
      else
     {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
     }
      selectLanguage = [List objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       [self checkedCellAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if([self getCheckedForIndex:indexPath.row]==NO)
      {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
   }
    else

      {
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
     }

     selectLanguage = [List objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    @end;
```

Comment: why, yes. thats exactly how you would do that. Now what?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this :

***Single Row Selection:***

create a new variable to track the index In Controller:

```
 int selectedIndex;
```

in UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex)
{
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

and in UITableView didSelectRowAtIndex method:

```
 selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
 [tableView reloadData];
```

***2 way as per you want:***

.h file:

```
NSIndexPath* checkedIndexPath;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath* checkedIndexPath;
```

.m file:

```
 @synthesize checkedIndexPath;

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

         //do you stuff here
        if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        return cell;
    }


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        //do work for checkmark
        if(self.checkedIndexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView
                                    cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
            uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
        {
            self.checkedIndexPath = nil;
        }
        else
        {
            UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;
        }
    }
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: ok Brother So what about save chekmark if first time i select row then after second time i reload the table my row already chekmarked? :)

Comment: you have to remove all checkmark in didselectrow method and set it again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41604/discussion-between-dhaval-bhadania-and-user2396021)

Comment: this code doesn't ensure one selection at all time. For at least one selection at all times, use the following code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:-- 

    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;