# Remove checkmark

Tags: ios, objective-c, cell

I have a tableView. If I click on the cell, it starts downloading file with `UIActivityIndicator` animation. Once the download is complete checkmark appears (the file exists), and the user can move to the next controller. Necessary that after move to the next controller and return back all checkmark disappeared. How to do it?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (indexPath.row == 1){
if (!fileExists) {
        [_spinner startAnimating];
    }
    if (fileExists) {
 cell.accessoryView = nil;
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
 }
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 2){
if (!fileExists1) {
        [_spinner1 startAnimating];
     }

        if (fileExists1) {
            cell.accessoryView = nil;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.row == 1) {

if (!fileExists) {
 _spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
 _spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.accessoryView = _spinner;
 tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = _spinner;
 [_spinner startAnimating];

if (fileExists) {
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more code like `cellForRowAtindexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @user check the answer, did this is your requirement?

Comment: @NiravD I update my question. Please check.

Comment: Basically do not manipulate the **view** (the cell) without updating also the **model** (the data source array). The next time the table view is reloaded only the current state in the model is considered.

Comment: May it help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045991/select-one-speicific-row-with-one-checkmark-using-uitbaleview/20113209#20113209

Answer (score 1):

Reload your tableview in viewWillAppear

Comment: `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}` I add in code but it is not work

Comment: once again check your tableview object, connection given or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check the result:

> [image: The result]

Follow my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *sel_indexPath;  // selected indexpath

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // cancel the checkmark

    if (self.sel_indexPath) {

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellId"];

    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    cell.textLabel.text = @"cell title";

    return  cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    self.sel_indexPath = indexPath;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"VC1GotoVC2" sender:self];
}

@end
```

Comment: I update my question. Please check. If I use  `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it is not work. checkmark appearance

Comment: @user you mean didselectrow not push to nextcontroller right now?

Answer (score 0):

If fileExists, reload your tableView in viewWillAppear. Use a model to mark the fileExists cell.

```
@interface CheckMarkModel ()

@property (assign, nonatomic,get=isFileExists) BOOL fileExists;

@end

@implementation CheckMarkModel

@end

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath selectIndexPath;  // select IndexPath

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dataArrM; // save select cell 
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // your cell count
    NSInteger cellCount = ;
    _dataArrM = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < cellCount; ++i)
    {   
        CheckMarkModel *model = [CheckMarkModel new];
        [_dataArrM addObject:model];
    }
    // reload
    [tableView reload];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId"];
    //....
    CheckMarkModel *model = _dataArrM[indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = (model.isFileExists) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return  cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (!self.isFileExists)
    {
        _selectIndexPath = indexPath;
        [self downloadFile];
        [self tableView:tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }else {
        // move to the next controller 
    }

}
- (void)downloadFile {
    // download action ...

    //download success
    if (fileExists) {
        CheckMarkModel *model = _dataArrM[_selectIndexPath.row];
        model.fileExists = YES; 
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[_selectIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];     
    }   
}
@end
```